# iOS app run fast in iphone 5 but slow in iPAD Air

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, ipad

I am developing a graphic intensive game in iOS7.

The app is tested in iphone 5 with good performance
but a bit lag and slower in iPAD air.

The CPU should be pretty much the same or iPAD air should be even faster.
But the rendering seems a bit slow in iPAD.

My app is in iOS7 based on iphone in XCode project.

are some plist parameters issue or app build setting issue?

Comment: I think your rendering code might need to be optimised, since the iPad has a higher resolution screen but (AFAIK) pretty much the same hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad Air actually has better hardware than iPhone 5.

**iPhone 5**

- 1.3 GHz dual-core Apple-designed ARMv7s Apple A6
- PowerVR SGX543MP3 (tri-core, 266 MHz) GPU
- 1GB LPDDR2 DRAM

**iPad Air**

- 1.4 GHz dual-core 64-bit Apple A7 SoC with M7 motion coprocessor
- PowerVR G6430 (4-core) GPU
- 1 GB LPDDR3 DRAM

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

I think the higher screen resolution of the iPad, though, actually makes for worse performance on it. I would suggest optimizing your code the way you would if it were slow on both devices.